# How can I take third image in condition in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, image

In my web application I have one condition like this:

```
Bitmap FinalBitmap = new Bitmap(img2.Width > img1.Width ? img2.Width 
                   : img1.Width, img1.Height + img2.Height)
```

In this condition how can I take another img3.

Comment: Something like: `Bitmap FinalBitmap = new Bitmap(img2.Width > img1.Width ? (img2.Width > img3.Width ? img2.Width : img3.Width) : (img1.Width > img3.Width ? : img1.Width : img3.Width), img1.Height + img2.Height + img3.Height)`

Comment: Hi thank you for reply. but Getting errors when i tried with code it is not useful. tell me another way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linq would be great here, with Enumerable.Max and Enumerable.Sum:

```
var images = new[] {img1, img2, img3};
Bitmap finalBitmap = new Bitmap(images.Max(img => img.Width), images.Sum(img => img.Height));
```

Answer (score 0):

If we stick to your coding style then something like:

```
Bitmap FinalBitmap = new Bitmap(img2.Width > img1.Width ?
  (img2.Width > img3.Width ? img2.Width : img3.Width) :
  (img1.Width > img3.Width ? : img1.Width : img3.Width),
  img1.Height + img2.Height + img3.Height);
```

But I'd do it a bit differently using [Math.Max](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cs0a3045(v=vs.110).aspx) instead:

```
Bitmap finalBitmap = new Bitmap(
  Math.Max(img1.Width, Math.Max(img2.Width, img3.Width)),
  img1.Height + img2.Height + img3.Height);
```